# Diffeomorphism of closure of open sets

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $F:\overline{X} \to \overline{Y}$ be a map between the closure of two open Lipschitz domains $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with boundaries). $F$ is such that it maps $X$ to $Y$ and it maps $\partial X$ to $\partial Y$.

If $F:\overline{X} \to \overline{Y}$ is $C^r$-diffeomorphism, does it follow that $F|_{X}:X \to Y$ and $F|_{\partial X}:\partial X \to \partial Y$ are also $C^r$-diffeomorphisms?

I think the answer is yes because it maps boundary to boundary.

**Edit**: it seems like I need all $r$ derivatives of $F$ to also map interior to interior and boundary to boundary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true. First thing you should note is that the interior of $\overline{X}$ is $X$ (this is not true for general domains, but works for Lipschitz domains). Any homeomorphism of two subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ maps interior to interior and boundary to boundary; this is because interior points are distinguished by the property of having a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, and this property is invariant under homeomorphism.

Smoothness of restriction to $X$ is not a problem: the restriction of a map to any open subset of its domain preserves all local properties such as smoothness. For restriction to the boundary, you need to unwind your definition of "smooth map of $\partial X$" (how do you defined it without assuming $\partial X$ itself smooth?), but it should be routine.

> need all $r$ derivatives of $F$ to also map interior to interior and boundary to boundary.

This is nonsense, and you don't need any such thing. You should not even think of derivatives as something that takes values in $\mathbb R^n$ where $Y$ lives. They take values in tangent spaces to $\mathbb R^n$, which is a different space altogether.